# Table Row Refresh in Oracle Application Framework

Tags: oracle, application-framework

Is there a way to refresh only few rows of a Table Region in OAF (Oracle Application Framework)?

Comment: do you tried adding partial triggers?

Comment: Oracle EBS questions are commonly left unanswered here, i suggest you head over to the Oracle Forums (community.oracle.com), you have a better chance to get answers there.